# How to get the total number of items in arrays deeply nested in an object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Count the sub_sub part of the data array as shown below,
I want to display it on the console as shown below.

```
3
1
```

sample data↓

```
    const items = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "a",
        sub: [
            {
                id: "1#1",
                name: "b",
                sub_sub: [
                    { id: "1#1#1", name: "b-a" },
                    { id: "1#1#2", name: "b-b" },
                ]
            },
            {
                id: "1#2",
                name: "c",
                sub_sub: [
                    { id: "1#2#1", name: "c-a" },
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "d",
        sub: [
            {
                id: "2#1",
                name: "e",
                sub_sub: [
                    { id: "1#2#1", name: "e-a" },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Count the number of sub_sub arrays contained in name: "a" and name: "d",
I want to display it.
An error is displayed and it is not executed.

"error message in console"
Cannot read property 'items' of undefined at sub_lenght_calc

Could anyone advise me, please?
My code is below.

```
   function sub_lenght_calc(id:any){
        if(this.items.sub.sub_sub.length !== 0){
                for(let i = 0; i<this.items.sub.length ;i++){
                    const sub_sub_lenght = this.items.sub.sub_sub.forEach((element:any) => {
                      return  element.length ++
                    });
                }
                console.log(this.sub_sub_lenght);
        }

    }

sub_lenght_calc()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
 const items = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "a",
        sub: [
            {
                id: "1#1",
                name: "b",
                sub_sub: [
                    { id: "1#1#1", name: "b-a" },
                    { id: "1#1#2", name: "b-b" },
                ]
            },
            {
                id: "1#2",
                name: "c",
                sub_sub: [
                    { id: "1#2#1", name: "c-a" },
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "d",
        sub: [
            {
                id: "2#1",
                name: "e",
                sub_sub: [
                    { id: "1#2#1", name: "e-a" },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
]

items.forEach(el => {
  const count = el.sub.reduce((total, curr) => total + curr.sub_sub.length, 0);
  console.log(count);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your ansewr! I really appreciated it!!

Answer (score 2):

```js
 const items = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "a",
        sub: [
            {
                id: "1#1",
                name: "b",
                sub_sub: [
                    { id: "1#1#1", name: "b-a" },
                    { id: "1#1#2", name: "b-b" },
                ]
            },
            {
                id: "1#2",
                name: "c",
                sub_sub: [
                    { id: "1#2#1", name: "c-a" },
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "d",
        sub: [
            {
                id: "2#1",
                name: "e",
                sub_sub: [
                    { id: "1#2#1", name: "e-a" },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
]

const result = items.map(item => item['sub'].reduce((count, record) => count + record['sub_sub'].length, 0));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I was really surprised at how short the code was. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

by simple for loop

```js
const items = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "a",
        sub: [
            {
                id: "1#1",
                name: "b",
                sub_sub: [
                    { id: "1#1#1", name: "b-a" },
                    { id: "1#1#2", name: "b-b" },
                ]
            },
            {
                id: "1#2",
                name: "c",
                sub_sub: [
                    { id: "1#2#1", name: "c-a" },
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "d",
        sub: [
            {
                id: "2#1",
                name: "e",
                sub_sub: [
                    { id: "1#2#1", name: "e-a" },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
]

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    let temp = 0
    for (let j = 0; j < items[i].sub.length; j++) {
        temp += items[i].sub[j].sub_sub.length;
    }
    console.log(temp)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! it was really helpful!!

Comment: @drunkdolphin Welcome :)